# Prove that $|GL_n(\mathbb{F})|< q^{n^2}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\Bbb F$ be a finite field, say $|\Bbb F|=q$; then we know that $|GL_n(\Bbb F)| < \infty$.

> But how can we prove that $|GL_n(\mathbb{F})|< q^{n^2}$?

I'm guessing because there $n^2$ entries in a $n\times n$ matrix. A little background would be helpful for me about the proof as I am inexperience with algebra proofs.

Comment: The number $q^{n^2}$ is the number of all matrices $M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$. You have $n^2$ "slots" and for each you decide which element to put out of a set of order $q$.

Comment: @Ofir Schnabel Is M_n(F_q) just an element of GL_n (F)? What made you such notation?

Comment: $M_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices. You are looking for a subset.

Answer (score 6):

While the other answers lead you to the precise order of $GL_n(\mathbf{F})$, I'll explain a simple way to see the inequality you asked about.

As you note, any $n \times n$ matrix has $n^2$ entries; if these entries are coming from $\mathbf{F}$, then the set of all $n \times n$ matrices has order $q^{n^2}$, since there are $q$ choices for each of the $n^2$ entries. Thus, we have $|M_n(\mathbf{F})| = q^{n^2}$.

But the subgroup $GL_n(\mathbf{F})$ of *invertible* matrices is smaller -- not every $n \times n$ matrix is invertible! For instance, the $n \times n$ **zero** matrix is not invertible. So we see that $GL_n(\mathbf{F})$  **is strictly smaller than** $M_n(\mathbf{F})$. So we can conclude that

$$|GL_n(\mathbf{F})| <  q^{n^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

You have to count the number of independent columns whose entries are not all equal to zero. For the first one you have $q^n-1$ choices. Fixed this one, for the second one you have to count all the possible choices but the multiples of the first column: $q^n-q$.

So till now you have $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)$ choices.

For the third one you have to consider all the $q^n$ choices but the possible combination of the first two columns; these possibles are $q^2$ thus for the third column you have $q^n-q^2$ possibilities.

Hence for the first three columns you have $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)$ possibilities.

Going on till the $n$-th column, you easily get that all the possible choices for $n$ independent columns are $(q^n-1)(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)\dots(q^n-q^{n-1})$, which is exactly the cardinality of $GL_n(\Bbb F)$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, if $F$ is a field (you weren't clear about what $F$ is) such that $|F|=q<\infty$, then $\left|\text{GL}_n(F)\right|=\left(q^n-1\right)\left(q^n-q\right)\left(q^n-q^2\right)\cdots\left(q^n-q^{n-1}\right)$ (which clearly means $\left|\text{GL}_n(F)\right|<q^{n^2}$).  See http://www-math.mit.edu/~dav/genlin.pdf.